# Obj-C Taking server response for parameter and putting it into an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

So I am sending a http 'POST' request and getting a response using the code below...

```
static HistoryViewController *sharedInstance;

+(HistoryViewController *) getInstance
{
@synchronized (self) {
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[HistoryViewController alloc] init];
        sharedInstance.photo_URL =@"";
        return sharedInstance;
    }else{
        return sharedInstance;
    }
  }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];    
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultConfigObject delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];    
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.MyURL/getPhotos.php"];   
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];    
NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"parameter=%@", parameter];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
    if(error == nil)
    {
        NSString *text =[[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];            
        NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);            
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
        [HistoryViewController getInstance].photo_URL = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"photoURL"];

    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

And my response from the server looks like this...

```
"<MyURLResponse><photoURL>photoURLexample</photoURL><created>04/12/2019 at 8:58 am EDT</created></MyURLResponse>"
```

Thats only one photo but when more photos get uploaded to the sight it will return all of them. When I try taking the data from the JSON dictionary it comes back 'null' What should I do to put the responses between the `<photoURL>` into a dictionary or array?

Comment: I found out how to do it, the best way of doing this is using an XML parser if anyone sees this

Comment: Answered my own question

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices.
1. Generate the NSArray using NSString's API, such as "componentsSeparatedByString:". The parameter should be defined in substring between  and ;
2. Use NSObject+YYModel. 
https://github.com/ibireme/YYModel